# Reloading view objects when I replace fragments in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to switch between 5 Fragments on 1 Activity using the Bottom Navigation View object. My problem is:i am going FragmentA to FragmentB. then when I return to FragmentA, my objects in FragmentA are reloaded. I don't want this to happen. Thanks in advance for your help. 
My Activity codes

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navigation_home -> {
            val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
            openFragment(homeFragment)
            actionBar?.setTitle(R.string.title_home)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_campaign -> {
            val campaignFragment = CampaignFragment()
            openFragment(campaignFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_categories -> {
            val categoriesFragment = CategoriesFragment()
            openFragment(categoriesFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_user_account -> {
            val userAccountFragment = UserAccountFragment()
            openFragment(userAccountFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_cart -> {
          /* val cartFragment = CartFragment.newInstance()
            openFragment(cartFragment)*/
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}

private fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.design_bottom_sheet_slide_in, R.anim.design_bottom_sheet_slide_out)
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.javaClass.getSimpleName())
            .addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.getSimpleName())
            .commit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then use `viewPager` to hold your fragments and navigate within it.

Your navigation click listeners will fire `viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageIndex)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **replace** - use **add** and then you may get back to previous fragment thanks to **supportFragmentManager().popBackStack()** that you can handle in **onBackPressed()**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new fragment on each onclick call, you can create a member variable of the fragment.

remove the assignments from the onClick method and add it as a member variable to the class

example,

```
class MyActivity ...{
    val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    val campaignFragment = CampaignFragment()
    val categoriesFragment = CategoriesFragment()
    val userAccountFragment = UserAccountFragment()
    //  val cartFragment = CartFragment.newInstance()

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                openFragment(homeFragment)
                actionBar?.setTitle(R.string.title_home)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_campaign -> {
                openFragment(campaignFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_categories -> {
                openFragment(categoriesFragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_user_account -> {
            openFragment(userAccountFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_cart -> {
              /* openFragment(cartFragment)*/
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use fragment tags instead of holding the reference to the fragments

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue in my project. Here is my solution

```
fun openTab(tabId: String, fragmentClass: String, props: Bundle, manager: FragmentManager) {
    if (manager.fragments.isEmpty() || manager.findFragmentByTag(tabId) == null) {
        val fragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, fragmentClass, props)
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        if (manager.backStackEntryCount != 0) {
            manager.fragments.forEach {
                transaction.hide(it)
            }
        }
        transaction.add(contentViewId, fragment, tabId)
        transaction.commit()
    } else {
        val tabFragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(tabId)
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        manager.fragments.forEach {
            transaction.hide(it)
        }

        tabFragment?.let { transaction.show(it).commitNow() }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to get this method's parameters

Comment: tabId: whatever you prefer something like "home", "campaign", "categories", etc... ||
fragmentClass: for example HomeFragment.getClass().getName() ||
props: Doesn't seem you need it so you can just remove this parameter from method ||
manager: supportFragmentManager